# How to substract numbers within a string in PHP?

Tags: php

There is a string variable containing number data , say `$x = "OP/12/DIR";` . The position of the number data may change at any circumstance by user desire by modifying it inside the application , and the slash bar may be changed by any other character ; but the number data is mandatory. So how to extract the number data from the string ?

Comment: Is the number always surrounded by `/` in the string? That would let you do an easy explode rather than a (possibly) nasty preg. Ugh, nevermind, I can't read.

Comment: @Fluffeh "and the slash bar may be changed by any other character"

Comment: the number is not always surrounded by `/` !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace everything that is NOT a number with an empty string.

```
  $numbers = preg_replace('/[^0-9]*/','',$x);
```

Comment: That's going to be rather nasty if the rest of the information needs to be maintained?

Comment: Also true. I think I need to quit while I am behind with comments on this question :)

Answer (score 1):

Replace everithing that is not a number:

```
  $numbers = preg_replace( '/[^\d\.]/', '', $input );
```

or if you will have decimal:

```
$numbers = preg_replace ( '#\D*?(\d+(\.\d+)?)\D*#', '$1', $input );
```